# Split string in trio and join with a dot from right to left with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing a rule for an input, and the rule is ok.

The problem is to format the input after the rule.

I need this:

```
String.prototype.myFormat = function(){

    // ...

};

var example1 = "habc123def".myFormat(); // should return "h.abc.123.def"
var example2 = "12a45".myFormat();      // should return "12.a45"
```

I don't know if *regex* could help here because the string length is unknown.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not getting the rule, honestly... In any case the string length is not a problem with regex.

Comment: Sure a regex (or two) could handle that. But you don't specify what the myFormat should do. The two examples point to more complex logic than your title implies.

Comment: It's delimited in sets of three from right to left.

Comment: reverse the string and then split.

Comment: @ray: thanks, that was not that evident though! :P

Comment: agreed. took me a minute to figure that out.

Comment: @ray: surprisingly anubhava found that out way earlier than we did... That guy is insane, lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex replacement:

```
var str = 'habc123def';
str = str.replace(/(?=(.{3})+$)/gm, ".");
//=> h.abc.123.def

str = '12a45';
str = str.replace(/(?=(.{3})+$)/gm, ".");
//=> 12.a45
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG7mF7/1)

Comment: Why can't I use `?=.{3}` but `?=(.{3})` ?

Comment: Because we're making sure multiple of those 3 character strings before `$` using `(?=(.{3})+$)`. It can also be: `(?=(?:.{3})+$)`

Comment: that is some sexy code.  i did it in a while loop, but i dont even want to put forth the code because thats so sexy :)

Comment: Worth to mention that `'habc123def'.split(/(?=(?:.{3})+$)/g)` with unmached group will show the array without inner matches

Comment: Just a note if you want to avoid `abc` becoming `.abc` then use `/(?!^)(?=(?:.{3})+$)/gm` [See this demo](https://regex101.com/r/gG7mF7/2)

Answer (score 1):

A way that uses the modulo:

```
String.prototype.myFormat = function() {
    var mod = this.length % 3 || 3;
    return this.slice(0, mod) + this.slice(mod).replace(/.{3}/g, '.$&');
};

var str = "abc123def";

console.log(str.myFormat());
```

In this way, there is no leading dot when the string length is a multiple of 3.

Comment: You guys are incredible !